# Add pdf file to custom product type

Tags: product, pdf

I have made one custom product type. In this I want to allow the admin to add any pdf from admin side which will be allowed for the visitor to download on frontend side.

So please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: Why did not tried with download product type

Comment: I need to add a different product type based on client's requirement